# I cannot install mysql module for flask

Tags: python, mysql, database, web, flask

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\vin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\ViN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fxzjh985\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ViN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fxzjh985\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ViN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-aqekzrrq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\vin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\ViN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fxzjh985\mysqlclient\
    Complete output (30 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\compat.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include\mariadb" -Ic:\users\vin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\vin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /Zl /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    _mysql.c
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c(29): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'mysql.h': No such file or directory
    error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\vin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\ViN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fxzjh985\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\ViN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-fxzjh985\mysqlclient\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ViN\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-aqekzrrq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\vin\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.

i am getting the error mentioned above, please help.

Comment: Hi @vin you would be better off searching for questions similar to your's first. You might find what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks a lot @The_Cthulhu_Kid i figured it out. i was using a version of python that was not compatible   with my os lol.

Comment: Awesome! Maybe add how you found it as an answer so than anyone else who has a similar problem might get some help =)